# Input currently not working while trying to launch it with CMD

Tags: python-3.x, input, cmd

I'm currently reading a book, and one of the exercises requires me to put the following code:

```
name = input("What's your name? ")

filename = 'guest.txt'

with open(filename, 'w') as f:
    f.write(name)
```

When I try to launch it in CMD (used to work on other input exercises), it just leaves a blank line, it never asks me for my name and it doesn't write anything to guest.txt. Is there anything wrong with this, or something extra I need to do? (Sorry if it seems too basic, I am just a beginner Python programmer who is now slowly learning)
EDIT 1: Here is the output of CMD

```
C:\Users\gabyp\Documents\python_work\chapter_10\chapter_10_practice_2>chapter_10_practice_2.py

C:\Users\gabyp\Documents\python_work\chapter_10\chapter_10_practice_2>
```

As you can see, there is no error message or anything, it's like if it never launched!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are facing this problem because of a minor mistake,

you are executing your program using

```
chapter_10_practice_2.py
```

but it should be

```
python chapter_10_practice_2.py
```

Hope this helps you!